# Is "UX" as an abbreviation for "user experience" meant to be ironic?

Tags: terminology, ux-field

I am wondering about the origins of the "X" in "UX" as an abbreviation for *user experience*.

Has *UX* become a standard abbreviation because the people in this field find the term amusing? My thinking is that a software user interface that uses shorthand abbreviations might not be considered to have a good user experience (at least, not at software companies where I have worked). Especially in this case, as the meaning of the *X* is unintuitive for anyone who has not encountered the term before (*X* could be taken to mean *cross*, a multiplication sign, the number *ten*, or even a syntactic wildcard).

The irony of using *UX* as an abbreviation for *user experience* must not be lost on user experience and usability experts. So has *UX* gained popularity because the specialists in this field have a sense of humour, and the term *UX* is ironic and amusing?

Comment: It's a nice theory, but 'X' is a common way to abbreviate any word beginning with *x... so it's likely due to common usage more than anything. As for concerns about people outside the world of UX, it's somewhat moot as the term is really a term solely used internally. All fields have their own jargon. This is one of ours.

Comment: It's XTREME!! Not boring, like "UE" is. Ho hum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like **@DA01** mentioned in their comment, is a common way to abbreviate any word beginning with ***x**.

That said, in this specific instance, **Experience** begins with ***Ex*** and the pronunciation of that is ***Eks***, the same pronunciation as the letter ***X***, which makes ***UX*** a perfect abbreviation for ***User Experience***.

Answer (score 7):

It's not like we're special:

**AX** Analyst Executive

**BX** Base Exchange

**CX** Customer Experience

**DX** Direct Exchange

**FX** Foreign Exchange

**GX** Global Exchange

**HX** Heat Exchanger

**IX** International Exchange

**LX** Lower Extremity

**MX** Mail Exchange

**NX** No Execute

**PX** Post/Part Exchange

**RX** Recieve

**SX** Securities Exchange

**TX** Transmit

**UX** User Experience

**VX** Virtual Experience

**WX** Weather Information

Comment: You've just made some of these up, surely! ;) (WX=Weather Information?)

Comment: I know that **Hx** is used as shorthand to denote "History" in emergency medicine.

Comment: The x is very common in medical environments to denote the rest of a common word rather than a second word starting ex... Sx for Symptoms, Px for Prescription, Dx Diagnosis, Fx Family, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Xp was launched in the early zeros when UX was taking off.

The Xp stands for experience, and will have popularised the removal of the first 'e'

The UX term has tended to replace the earlier terms HCI and Usability